# How to return to the client all rows from a dynamic pl-sql query

Tags: c#, oracle, plsql

I'm pretty new to PL-SQL (I've previous background in T-SQL) and I'm working on an application (.NET C#) that will execute a RAW SQL against an Oracle Database, the SQL is a Dynamic query that will add or remove 'where' conditions depending on some values I will check in the user's input screen, so the SQL is a raw sql not a stored procedure or a function.

The PL-SQL looks something like this:

```
DECLARE
  myvar1 VARCHAR2(3000) := '';
  myvar2 VARCHAR2(3000) := '';
  myvar3 VARCHAR2(3000) := '';
  myvar4 VARCHAR2(3000) := '';
  myvar5 VARCHAR2(3000) := '';
  DynaSql VARCHAR2(3000) := '';
BEGIN
  DynaSql := '--all the sql';

  IF myvar1 <> '' AND myvar2 <> '' THEN
    DynaSql := DynaSql || ' --do something with myvar3';

    IF myvar3 <> '' THEN
      DynaSql := DynaSql || ' --do something with myvar4';
    END IF;

  ELSE 

    IF myvar4 <> '' THEN
      DynaSql := DynaSql || ' --do something with myvar5';
    END IF;

  END IF;

  --Here I need to return all rows (datasource)

END;
```

I've no idea how to just return all rows, the SQL don't return any specific table row, is a brand new column that exists only here in that query, so I can not simple map to an existing table, I've seen many online samples where is required to use a cursor to fill variables for each field, but I do not understand why is that needed, I will just return the data.

I will appreciate your help

Comment: In PL/SQL you can't  directly "RETURN DATA" as in T-SQL. you can return a cursor or collection if you like but you either need a logic to define the columns you need to fetch or create a predefined collection object type  with all the rows. In Oracle 12c, however, your best bet is `DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT`, however, its not equivalent to returning data.

Comment: Can't you just build the dynamic SQL in C# and then execute the final statement?

Comment: @Mt.Schneiders Yes I can, but I was looking for something on the PL-SQL side